# Jsoup, подскажите как построить логику проверки наличия и получения элемента

Tags: java, jsoup

```
<TaskLifetimeList ml-is-active="">
<TaskLifetimes>
<TaskLifetime>...</TaskLifetime>
<TaskLifetime>...</TaskLifetime>
<TaskLifetime>...</TaskLifetime>
<TaskLifetime>
<Comments>
<![CDATA[
подготовить    ]]>
</Comments>
<IsPublic>True</IsPublic>
<Date>19.04.2018 13:00:19</Date>
<EditorId>9017</EditorId>
<Editor>ААААААААААААА</Editor>
<Executors>ВВВВВВВВВВ</Executors>
<ExecutorsGroup>БББББББББББ</ExecutorsGroup>
<Participants>АААААА</Participants>
<StatusId>35</StatusId>
</TaskLifetime>
<TaskLifetime>...</TaskLifetime>
<TaskLifetime>...</TaskLifetime>
</TaskLifetimes>
<Paginator>...</Paginator>
</TaskLifetimeList>
```

Как видите есть список `TaskLifeTime`. Один из них я для наглядности раскрыл. Задача: Узнать в каком из тегов `TaskLifeTime` содержится тег `ExecutorsGroup` (если парсинг идет сверху вниз, то самое первое совпадение с тегом  `ExecutorsGroup` и нужно.) И взять строку из тега `Date` , того элемента в котором нашел `ExecutorsGroup`. 
  Вопрос в том как это сделать максимально эффективно. Логику с передачей каждого `TaskLifeTime` в массив и потом не хотелось бы. Как использовать грамотно возможности парсера jsoup. Еще раз повторюсь, речь не идет о добавлении каждого родительского тега в массив и искать по отдельности.  Я смутно знаю что можно идти в обратную строну от дочернего тега, не зная какой тег родительский. 
 Нашел способ правильно выразить свои мысли: Нужно по тегу найти элемент и потом найти в родительском элементе значение другого тега `Date`, т.е. нашел один тег и получить другой тег на этой же уровне иерархии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял и вам нужно получить только даты, то это будет выглядить так:

```
public List<Date> getDates() throws IOException, ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("some-url").get();

    Elements elements = document.select("TaskLifetimeList TaskLifetimes TaskLifetime ExecutorsGroup");

    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Element item : elements) {
        String date = item.parent().selectFirst("Date").text();
        dates.add(format.parse(date));
    }

    return dates;
}
```

Если вам нужно получить первый элемнт делайте это так:

```
document.selectFirst("TaskLifetimeList TaskLifetimes TaskLifetime ExecutorsGroup")
        .parent()
        .selectFirst("Date").text();
return format.parse(date);
```

Comment: Ваше решение как раз такое, о котором я писал, что оно не нужно. Ваш подход получить все TaskLifeTime в массив и в том котором найдем "ExecutorsGroup" берем и "Date".   А я ищу такой способ: как то узнаем вообще о наличии такого тега как ExecutorsGroup и если он существует, получаем путь к его родителю к которому прибавив Date получим нужное.

Comment: @Turalllb Пересмотрите код, я его обновил, там селектятса все элементы в котором есть нужный вам тег. Если найдете более эффективный способ нежели нативный css-selector то делитесь

Comment: точно. Можно и так. я сразу не заметил что можно сразу получить один элемент в котором есть нужный тег . Как думаете методом parent() работает используя DOM ? (может как то не правильно выразился)

Comment: А как же быть если вдруг окажется два TaskLifitime в которых есть ExecutorsGroup ? Мне нужен только тот что сверху , так как там последняя Дата. Можно же Elements заменить на Element и я получу первый попавшийся ?

Comment: Мне просто не нужен массив с Датами. А только одна дата , последняя по времени и она расположена вверху.

Comment: @Turalllb обновил

Comment: Вот, то что нужно, коротко и ясно. Спасибо, не знал, о существовании метода parent() , его функционал в общем то и искал